# What do I gain by filtering URLs through Perl's URI module?

Tags: perl, url, uri

Do I gain something when I transform my `$url` like this: `$url = URI->new( $url )`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings; use strict;
use 5.012;
use URI;
use XML::LibXML;

my $url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
$url = URI->new( $url );

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_html( location => $url, recover => 2 );
my @nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'a' );
say scalar @nodes;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [URI module constructor](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI.pm#CONSTRUCTORS) would clean up the URI for you - for example correctly escape the characters invalid for URI construction (see [URI::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI/Escape.pm)).

Answer (score 3):

The [URI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI) module as several benefits:

- It normalizes the URL for you
- It can resolve relative URLs
- It can detect invalid URLs (although you need to turn off the schemeless bits)
- You can easily filter the URLs that you want to process.

The benefit that you get with the little bit of code that you show is minimal, but as you continue to work on the problem, perhaps spidering the site, URI becomes more handy as you select what to do next.

Comment: "It can detect invalid URLs (although you need to turn off the schemeless bits)" - I'd like to do that, but how? I've found the URI constructor to be very liberal in what it expects - which might be because it deals with many schemes. I'm looking for something to validate an HTTP/S URL. Should be easy to write something that does the job, but I'd hate to reinvent the wheel when the `URI` module is there to roll the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned it yet, but`$url = URI->new( $url );` doesn't clean up your `$url` and hand it back to you, it creates a new object of class `URI` (or, rather, of one if its subclasses) which can then be passed to other code which requires a `URI` object.  That's not particularly important in this case, since `XML::LibXML` appears to be happy to accept locations as either strings or objects, but some other modules require you to give them a `URI` object and will reject URLs presented as plain strings.

Comment: Well, I didn't mention it because it's implied that a constructor is giving you back an object. This object, however, has stringification overloaded so you can also just treat it like a string.